# Typing Out Nuclear/Symbol Equations

Tags: applications, mac

Is there any way on typing out nuclear equations/symbol equations (With the two numbers at the top and bottom in front of the element)?

One of my friends have used an app that does this for him automatically, but he refused to tell me the name of the app.

An example of the result would be:
[image]

Comment: If you're set on finding the application your friend used, and you don't see it here, you could flag your post and ask a mod to move it to the [TeX StackExchange Site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) :).

Answer (score 4):

There's an online LaTeX editor here: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

To express the example you gave, just enter this in the box:
`_{6}^{14}\textrm{C}`

The site will generate the image for you

Comment: There is a specific Mac app that I saw him use while he was constructing the letter (And it came out as characters instead of images.) Anything like this exist?

Comment: There are several typesetting UI apps for OS X that use TeX behind the scenes. Search for OS X apps for LaTeX. Note that LaTeX can be pretty complicated for advanced layouts and typesetting, but if all you want to do is generate some chemical symbols or equations and paste them into another document (e.g., Word, Pages), then a simple WYSIWYG LaTeX app (or site) should work.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX will offer the best results, but you can also use OpenOffice Math:

[image]

Comment: Eh, this can often get you part of the way, but LaTeX is a much more precise, more powerful solution for serious equation and technical symbol typesetting.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps he used [LaTeXiT](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit.php)? Anyway, quite childish of him not to tell you.